# Objective-C: Outside class variable definition through function

Tags: objective-c

I've got from previous developer inheritance where the variable defined outside the class:

```
StaticItemsList[] = {
    @"Item1", @"Item2", @"Item3"
};

@implementation
-(void) someMethod {}
@end
```

And this variable using in many classes directly from global. For now I need to make this variable definition through function. What the way in this case to do it? I can't to put it inside of class without huge trubles because of very complex logic inside of application.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to make this variable definition through function?"

Comment: I mean that this Variable defined statically in global and used in many ways in application in a huge list of classes within complex logic. For now need to make this variable definition by function.

Comment: Do you mean you want the value assigned once, based on results of a function? Or do you mean you want a function called every time so that the results can change over time?

Comment: Yes. Value assigned once, based on results of a function in global scope.

Comment: So static list is actually dynamic. The answer depends on many things: how you list got generated, which type it have. In your snipper you have array, how you find out array size. Is it function can be performed on compile time or not. Does it should be initialized after some other global variable or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the value at some early part of your program. A common point for iOS is `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, though this can be a bit late (many things run before this method). `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is a bit earlier, and can be a better choice for this kind of initialization, though it's still relatively late in the launch process.

If you need to ensure it's run earlier, you can put it in `main()` before the UIApplication starts. But remember that a lot of things you might expect to be around (like a run loop) aren't available that early.

If none of those approaches are early enough, you can create a global C++ object that assigns this value in its constructor. Global C++ objects are constructed even before `main()` is run. You can also do this by marking your C function `__attribute__(constructor)` (though I've never used this attribute personally, so I can't comment on it particularly).

Comment: Thx will try to do it