# Objective-C: How to define static const struct dynamically?

Tags: objective-c

I know that the topic is looking super strange but I've got from previous developer very strange approach for developing menu. The Menu Items is in Statical Structure and it's spreaded through a lot of classes and it's defined in global scope. Something like this:

```
static const struct {} Struct[] = {
    Item1, Item2, Item3
}
```

Is there any way to assign this structure dynamically? I need this structure make dependable on language parameter.

The class that is making this view inheriting UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

Comment: Is there a difference between this question and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307425/objective-c-outside-class-variable-definition-through-function?

Comment: Yes. There are. But all of it loking similar. Just got the project within inheritance. At previous message about global variable. for now about data in defined structure. The previous developer has been developing everything based on statical data primitives. It's extremely hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing strange about the approach if the Menu Items are relatively static which in many UIs that could be the case and that was the requirements for the previous developer.

You will have refactor the code. Perhaps the references to the struct menu items can remain intact but the struct can no longer be a constant.